# XF requires .NETFramework >= v4.6.1. You have 'v4.5.1'

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, package

When compile or debug a package project (.wapproj) with inside a Xamarin Form UWP application, recevive this error:
XF requires .NETFramework >= v4.6.1. You have 'v4.5.1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on .wapproj

```
<Project ...>
  ...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <XFDisableFrameworkVersionValidation>True</XFDisableFrameworkVersionValidation>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Last VS 2019 update 16.9.2 resolve this issue for me.

Try it.

Carbonete